# How to add large image into PDF (in multiple pages) using Alivepdf in Flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I want to add one large image into PDF (in multiple pages). For that I used image snapshot for image. I want to split complete byte array into chunks and using addimage I want to add it into PDF in multiple pages.

```
ImageSnapshot imageSnapshot = ImageSnapshot.captureImage(imgCanvas,0, new JPEGEncoder(),true);
var byteArr:ByteArray=new ByteArray();
byteArr.writeBytes(imageSnapshot.data,0,imageSnapshot.data.length); 
var myPDFEncoder:PDF = new PDF ( Orientation.PORTRAIT, Unit.MM,Size.A4);
myPDFEncoder.setDisplayMode(Display.FULL_PAGE);
myPDFEncoder.addPage();
myPDFEncoder.addImageStream(byteArr, 0, 0,targetImage.width,targetImage.height, 1, ResizeMode.FIT_TO_PAGE);
var bytes:ByteArray = myPDFEncoder.save(Method.LOCAL);
var fx:FileReference = new FileReference();
fx.save(bytes,"sample.pdf");
```

Comment: Why not make multiple snapshots (bytearrays) for each page piece (`draw` smaller rectangles) this would be easier than calculations to split one larger byte array. Otherwise show how you've tried to split the bytes.

Comment: In above code when i am trying to change offset value in writebytes it gives error  Error #2006: The supplied index is out of bounds.